# Found `once` in ident position

Tags: rust

I just got this error:

```
/home/conradk/MyFiles/Dev/console-rs/src/lib.rs:26:8: 26:12 error: found `once` in ident position
```

With the following Rust code:

```
struct Occur;

impl Occur {
    fn once() -> getopts::Occur {
        getopts::Req
    }

    fn at_most_once() -> getopts::Occur {
        getopts::Optional
    }

    fn zero_or_more_times() -> getopts::Occur {
        getopts::Multi
    }
}
```

With the following compiler / cargo versions:

```
rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (d7cfc34a2 2014-08-02 00:31:03 +0000)
cargo 0.0.1-pre-nightly (4a69ffa 2014-07-29 21:30:40 +0000)
```

Is `once` a keyword or something part of the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`once` is a reserved but more-or-less unused keyword. (It can actually be accessed—`once ||` is still a valid type—but it’s not being tested at all and could easily be broken.) This is largely for historical reasons; nothing really uses it at present, and I do not believe there are any plans to use it again. Perhaps it should be unreserved.

The place it was used was in marking closures as only being called once, to allow the borrow checker to reason about certain things. What is currently `|args| -> T` used to be `&fn(args) -> T` and what is currently `proc(args) -> T` used to be `~once fn(args) -> T`.